# Sed Replace return error

Tags: bash, sed, quoting

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e ’s/var\/www\/html/var\/www\/this_new_html/g’ {} \;
```

I tried to run the above to replace all my file that have the following

```
include_once '/var/www/html/inc/functions.php';
```

into

```
include_once '/var/www/this_new_html/inc/functions.php';
```

I had many includes line so using a mass replace sed replace would be good but when I run the code

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e ’s/var\/www\/html/var\/www\/this_new_html/g’ {} \;
```

The error print out was

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'
```

How do i change to make it working to replace

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `’`, use single quotes `'`. Also, I recommend using a different delimiter when working with paths. Using `#` will improve readability significantly:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's#var/www/html#var/www/this_new_html#g' {} +
```